# HTML How to align 3 element on the same line

Tags: html, asp.net

I see a lot of questions about this argument, but I can't able to solve my problem yet. 
I have 3 elements, and I want to align them in the same line.

This is my HTML code:

```
 <div>
      <a class="sxprova" href="javascript:scroll_modules(-1);">&lt;</a>

      <ul class="nav" id="ModuleContainer" runat="server" style="margin-right:20px; float:initial">
      </ul>

      <a class="dxprova" href="javascript:scroll_modules(1);">&gt;</a>
 </div>
```

and this is my CSS code :

```
 .sxprova {


     float:left;
     padding: 17px 5px;
     z-index: 100;
     font-weight: bold;
     border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
     background-color: rgb(223,223,223);
 }




 .dxprova {


     float:right;
     border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
     padding: 17px 5px;
     z-index: 100;
     font-weight: bold;
     background-color: rgb(223,223,223);
 }


    .nav {
        font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 13px;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 0 0 20px;
        margin: auto;
        background-color: rgb(223,223,223);
        width: 98%%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }
```

With this code the result is approximately the following:

[FIRSTELEMENT] [SECOND ELEMENT________________________________________________]
_________________________________________________________________[THIRD ELEMENT]

What I want is something like that:

[FIRSTELEMENT] [SECOND ELEMENT________________________________][THIRD ELEMENT]

Can someone help me?

Comment: It's an asp.net project.. ModuleContainer is a menù bar created programmatically in c#

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="nav" id="ModuleContainer" runat="server" style="margin-right:20px; float:left">
```

`ul` should also be left floated.

Comment: If i float it left , i have all 3 elements on the same row, but the ul width becomes, maybe, 20 % of the display and i have a lot of white space.. How i can fill all the line with the ul now?

Comment: Then don't apply float to the third element. It will solve your problem

Comment: Doesn't works without the right float. But with your first suggestion at least i have all the element on the same row ..

Comment: In that case please make third element also floated left

Comment: if i float right the third : 

[FIRST][SECOND__] WHITE SPACE [THIRD AT THE END]

if i float left the third: 

[FIRST][SECOND__] [THIRD ] WHITE SPACE At the end

Comment: let it be float left and remove ' margin-right:20px;' from inline css of UL

Answer (score 1):

Kindly, refer following demo to align 3 element on the same line. Working properly on Jsfiddle try this on your browser.

[Align 3 element on the same line](http://jsfiddle.net/7rg5a88h/)

**What I have changed:**

**1.** Added your html inside a **DIV** element.

```
<div id="dvContainer" class="container"> 
     ... Yout HTML Goes Here
</div>
```

**2.**  Changes done in **CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.sxprova {
    /*float:left;*/ -- Comment this out and add following
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.dxprova {
    /*float:right;*/ -- Comment this out and add following
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
ul {
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: initial;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    /*width: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;*/ -- Comment this out not required
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
```

Comment: Did u performed an `ctrl` + `r` to clear cache and reload CSS.

Comment: What problem did you faced when followed my example?

Comment: with your example i have 3 line , and all is "mashed"

Comment: I guess there's some conflict in CSS as this shouldn't happen. The example i provide is working properly. When it comes to CSS without looking at the cause of problem can't provide much help.

Comment: this is excatctly what happen : http://jsfiddle.net/7rg5a88h/1/ .. Ok i have to   modify the width..

Comment: Please check my updated answer **width** and **border** are not required in your case i forgot to remove them while posting solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your items in a div, and float two of them left, and the last one right. It's a very vague question, as you do not provide alot of information about your problem. I hope this solves your problem.

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v98z2pq5/)

Html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="item floatLeft"></div>
    <div class="item floatLeft"></div>
    <div class="item floatRight"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;

}

.item {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0 25px 0 0;
}

.floatLeft {
    float: left;
}

.floatRight {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: doesn't work.. this solution break my layout.. I don't know what other information give you :/

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your layout or css then. Did you check the fiddle ? Does it not act like that in your layout?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i find the solution.. I have to say thank you to @Parasmani Batra and Suprabhat for their suggestions.

```
 <div id="dvContainer" class="containerModule" style="background-color: rgb(223,223,223);">



                    <a class="sxprova" href="javascript:scroll_modules(-1);">&lt;</a>

                    <ul class="nav" id="ModuleContainer" runat="server" style="float:left">
                    </ul>

                    <a class="dxprova" href="javascript:scroll_modules(1);">&gt;</a>








        </div>
```

and the css:

```
 .nav {
        font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 13px;
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
        background-color: rgb(223,223,223);
        width: 100%%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }


.containerModule {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .sxprova {
        float: left;
        padding: 17px 5px;
        z-index: 100;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
        background-color: rgb(223,223,223);
    }

.dxprova {
        float: right;
        border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
        padding: 17px 5px;
        z-index: 100;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: rgb(223,223,223);
    }

ul {
        float: initial;
    }

        ul li {
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid #fff;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

i add the background color at the container to fill the bar until the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="item-list">
      <a class="sxprova" href="javascript:scroll_modules(-1);">&lt;</a>

      <ul class="nav" id="ModuleContainer" runat="server" style="height:51px;width:85%;float:left;margin:0 5px;">
              <li>1</li>
              <li>2</li>
              <li>3</li>
      </ul>

      <a class="dxprova" href="javascript:scroll_modules(1);">&gt;</a>
 </div>
```

Is this you are looking for -- [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gaurangnil/7rg5a88h/4/)